# How can I convert a nested part of a JSON object to dot-chained flat JSON?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, path, jq, flatten

I want this:

```
{
    "level1a": "value",
    "level1b": {
        "level2a": {
            "level3a": "nestedvalue"
        },
        "level2b": "value"
    }
}
```

To end up looking like this:

```
{
    "level1a": "value",
    "level1b": {
        "level2a.level3a": "nestedvalue",
        "level2b": "value"
    }
}
```

And then to this:

```
{
    "level1a": "value",
    "level1b": [{
            "key": "level2a.level3a",
            "val": "nestedvalue"
        },
        {
            "key": "level2b",
            "val": "value"
        }
    ]
}
```

I only want some nested fields to be dotted and I want to be able to choose which fields. I have a set of JSON documents that has thousands of fields, most of them nested under one or two first or second level fields.

Ultimately I then want to use something like jq's to_entries on the dot-chained fields to make then ready for ingestion into Elasticsearch as nested fields so as to keep the total number of fields low while still retaining all the information.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Isn't that ambiguous? Is a chained key "k.1.k.2" originally 1, 2, 3, or 4 levels?

Comment: I want to be able to select a key and make everything below it chained, as many levels as what might exist.None of the original keys have dots in them, so it will remain clear as to what the data used to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You evidently already know the solution to the second part of the problem, so here is a solution to the first part:

```
# linearize all paths of the input object or array
def dotkeys:
  def stringify: map(tostring) | join(".");
  . as $in
  | reduce paths(scalars) as $p (null;
     ($in|getpath($p)) as $v
     | setpath([$p|stringify]; $v));

def chain(key):
 .[key] |= dotkeys ;

chain("level1b")
```

### Output

With your input, this produces:

```
{
  "level1a": "value",
  "level1b": {
    "level2a.level3a": "nestedvalue",
    "level2b": "value"
  }
}
```